# When can I attach an event to an element loaded from PHP using angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a page that loads an element ( a div containing more div elements) via an angularjs directive. I need to attach an event to one of these divs that has a particular id. This is largely legacy code that I can't alter, but where I can, I'm replacing the jQuery with angularjs. But, alas, this piece has to have a jQuery function attached when the parent div is loaded. The ready() doesn't work, as the directive isn't called until after it runs. I thought the load() would work, since it runs after the directive, but when I set a breakpoint there and try to output the value of the parent div, it comes back as empty. So how can I attach my event to the div?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could attach the event to a parent (which is always present on the page):

```
$('.parent').on('click', '.specific_div_from_angularjs', function(){
  // Action here
}):
```

Or you could execute a function when the DOM is updated:

```
$('.parent').bind("DOMSubtreeModified propertychange",function(){
  // Code executed each time the DOM is modified
});
```

Comment: Thanks the DOMSubtreeModified propertychange did it.